# How can i grab all url patrameters in django

Tags: python, django

I have the downlaod link in my Django view , where the user can download the pdf forms. But i also need to
grab the all the URL parameters passed with the link.

I mean if user click on

`http://www.abc.com/download` then the simple pdf form will be downloaded

but i use click on

`http://www.abc.com/download?var1=20&var2=30&var3=40`

Then i need to get those parameters with their name and fill in fields.

That arguments can vary so i can't hard code those in view

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def my_view(request):
    get_args = request.GET #dict of arguments from a get request (like your example)
    post_args = request.POST #dict of arguments from a post request
    all_args = requst.REQUEST #dict of arguments regardless of request type.
```

Edit:
Based on your comment, you must be new to python.

#### Here are a few ways to access the items in your dictionary.

```
#This method will throw an exception if the key is not in the dict.
get_args['var1'] #represents the value for that key, in this case '20'

#This method will return None if the key is not in the dict.
get_args.get('var2') #represents the value for that key, in this case '30'
```

Or you could loop over the dict:

```
for key,val in get_args.items():
    do_something(val)
```

Comment: so dict will have key value pairs. how can i access indivial parametrs

Comment: See my last example with the for loop.  In every iteration of the loop you get the key and val variables for one item in the dict.

Comment: No problem, hope you like it!  Python is my language of choice.